# Resize/Scale equation in Beamer

Tags: math-mode, beamer, fontsize, scaling

I have a slide in my beamer presentation that looks like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.6\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{FvsD.png}
    \column{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}[c][.5\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[]<1> $a = 2.35\e{6}$ \\
        \item[]<1> $b = 1.72$ \\
        \item[]<1> $c = 2.00\e{4}$ \\
        \item[]<1> $d = 0.91$ \\
        \item[]<1> $e = 1.00$
    \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
\end{columns}
\begin{center}
    $F = a \cdot x^b + c \cdot sign(\dot x) \cdot x^d \cdot
    |\dot x|^e$
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I don't know much about beamer and this is probably a really stupid way to build the frame, but what I want to do is make the bottom equation bigger. Is there anyway to make just that section of math type larger?

Comment: Since this question isn't really about `beamer` but about general resizing techniques, I suggest you rename the title. (It probably already has been answered, but I haven't been around long enough to quickly locate it.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `\scalebox` or `\resizebox` from the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http;//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.6\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{FvsD.png}
    \column{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}[c][.5\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[]<1> $a = 2.35\e{6}$ \\
        \item[]<1> $b = 1.72$ \\
        \item[]<1> $c = 2.00\e{4}$ \\
        \item[]<1> $d = 0.91$ \\
        \item[]<1> $e = 1.00$
    \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
\end{columns}
\begin{center}
  \scalebox{2}{%
    $F = a \cdot x^b + c \cdot sign(\dot x) \cdot x^d \cdot | \dot x|^e$%
  }
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

`\scalebox{<factor>}{<stuff>}` scales `<stuff>` by a factor of `<factor>`, while `\resizebox{<width>}{<height>}{<stuff>}` does the same in terms of the lengths (or dimensions) `<width>` and `<height>`. If aspect ratio should be maintained, specify only one length and make the other `!`.

Answer (score 18):

Instead of keeping the small (normal) font size and scaling the equation to make it bigger, I would use a font command for it. If you simply use `\Huge` at the beginning of your center environment, you will get:

[image: Huge equation]

I used the *demo* option to get a black rectangle, because I did not have your picture. And I defined some `\e`. Besides that, the change was here:

```
\begin{center}
    \Huge
    $F = a \cdot x^b + c \cdot sign(\dot x) \cdot x^d \cdot
    |\dot x|^e$
\end{center}
```

Since `\Huge` has been used within an environment, the font size change is local to that. Instead of centering inline math, I would use displayed math, which is automatically centered:

```
{\Huge
  \[
    F = a \cdot x^b + c \cdot sign(\dot x) \cdot x^d \cdot|\dot x|^e
  \]}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Might be useful to note that it works with an `$...$` environment (it fails for me with an `$$...$$` environment).

Comment: @Benben `$$...$$` is TeX and not LaTeX, the LaTeX version would be `\[...\]`. And it should not be used in a LaTeX `center` environment.